# How to get json from csv file in row wise using flask

Tags: python, flask, postman

I  have written a code like :

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/df',methods=['POST','GET'])
def ff():
 df = pd.read_csv(r'dataframe_post.csv')
 row = [5, 'Sanjeev', 'AE']
 df.loc[len(df)] = row
 # print(dfs)
 ls=list(df.to_dict().values())
 return jsonify(ls)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and I am getting output as :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQSR0.png)

i.e all data is shown column-wise. But i want to display data as row wise. i.e. each entry individually

like;

```
[
  {
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Preeti", 
    "2": "CSE", 
  }, 
  {
    "id": 2, 
    "name": "Chinky", 
    "2": "CE", 
  }, 
          |
          |
          |
          |
          |
          |
]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In your `df.to_dict` call, use `to_dict(orient='records')` which will build the json row-wise

Answer (score 1):

To return json in your desired format you can use the built in dataframe method instead of listing and jsonifying:

```
df.to_json(orient="records")
```

This will give you a json encoded string as in the example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 'Sanjeev', 'AE'], [6, 'Sven', 'AA']], columns = ["id", "name", "2"])
```

Which returns:

```
   id     name   2
0   5  Sanjeev  AE
1   6     Sven  AA
```

And then as JSON:

```
df.to_json(orient="records")

'[{"id":5,"name":"Sanjeev","2":"AE"},{"id":6,"name":"Sven","2":"AA"}]'
```